# How can I create directly my own rss.xml in OctoberCMS?

Tags: rss, octobercms

I want to generate rss.xml file in OctoberCMS by manually. Other plugins cannot be customized what I want. How can generate it by my own hand? Any suggestion?

Comment: Check how "other plugins" are implemented and reimplement it the way you want.

Comment: "other plugins" don't have permanent link I tested it already for each item. And octoberCMS doesn't have a lot of plugins, only a few.

Comment: So, look how they are implemented and implement a better one. What exactly is your problem?

Comment: Actually, I want to create feed for apply facebook instant article. If I used other plugin and customized, it didn't work properly with facebook feed standard.

Comment: So, implement a new one, that does exactly what you want?

Comment: yes, but I don't know how to create my own feed directly. Create a new xml file and loop post in the file. I don't how to pass all post data to xml file too.

Comment: So, check how "other plugins" are implemented for that? (we've started going circles)

Comment: Already checked and try to implement but it has error often.

Comment: That's sad. What do you want from a community though?

Comment: hmm... it has less docs unlike wordpress. Hope the community gives full resources and keeps update with latest technology.

Comment: Well, then address the octobercms community to better document their product. Stackoverflow is a developers community. Do you have any particular development question at the moment?

Comment: nothing at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `File::put` method to place an XML file within the theme assets public folder.

```
File::put(themes_path('mytheme/assets/somefile.xml'), $xmlContents);
```

Comment: Thank you very much bro!!. Let me try it.